# Editing MS Access Table automatically updates website

Tags: sql, database, web-services, joomla

I am in charge of a fire department's website. We have multiple fundraisers through the year and I am looking for a way to upload the winners to the website, immediately as the winner is drawn, via MS Access or Excel. I am assuming Access is the way to go being as it incorporates SQL and ODBC. I am not stuck on just using MS products. If there is a way I can just do this via the front end of the website, I am okay with that too. 
I am the only one in the department that has any website background. 
I know this isn't a "do it for me" site, but I am just asking to be pointed in the right direction or some sort of starting point. I have searched many different topics and I just can't seem to find exactly what I want to do. I can provide more information if needed. Thanks in advance.

Comment: There are a number of things that could happen here. I am not at all sure why you say Access here? You have this tagged with sql server. Assuming that is correct you could use a trigger in sql server for this. Or you could even just have your page already built so that once there is data in the table or column that indicates a winner the page will pull that data. I am pretty sure this will get closed as "too broad" without a lot more details about your project.

Comment: I understand it's a broad topic, and I know there is not a lot of information. Basically what I am saying is, I am not stuck on any specific method, I am just looking for some direction. I have searched and searched and can't find what I am looking for. It was also supposed to be "sql" not "sql-server", I must have clicked the wrong one. Sorry about that

Comment: OK. So are you using a database? Is your website data driven or just hard coded pages?

Comment: I would prefer to use MS Access, but if there is an easier way, I am open to that too. I am using Joomla, so data driven

Comment: Is Access your existing database? If so why not just create a message on your page that uses a query? Something like "select WinnerName from SomeTable" or whatever. When there is no winner it won't show anything. As soon as there is data in your table it will show up with no additional effort at all.

Comment: So you're saying have some kind of an admin page where you can log in, select the time and the winning number and it will then run the query and populate the table? This is new to me, I can do websites and I can do databases, I have never combined the 2. Sorry, for my lack of knowledge on this

Comment: We were all new at one point. Not a problem there. I am saying you tie the two piece together. I don't know how or where you enter the winning info but make your page pull from the same table and your page will automatically update when the data updates. That is the whole point of a data driven site. :D

Comment: Okay, that gives me some information. Thanks for your help!